# Custom Json Validation in anypoint studio

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mule-el, mule-esb, spring-validator

I am trying to validate JSon using the json schema validator. But it returns a generic message.
"***Json content is not compliant with schema***" .
I have a HTTP POST REQUEST which sends a payload as follows:

> { "key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2" ,"key3": "value3" }

if key1 and key2 is missing . I want it to give error messages as follows:

```
{{
  errorCode :1001,
  errorMessage : key1 is missing",
},
  errorCode :1002,
  errorMessage : key2 is missing"
}
}
```

I tried writing the errors to a file(json file containing all the warnings and messages}
looks something like this:

```
{
  "level" : "error",
  "domain" : "validation",
  "keyword" : "required",
  "message" : "object has missing required properties ([\"key1\",\"key2\",\"key3\"])",
  "required" : [ "key1", "key2", "key3"],
  "missing" : [ "key1", "key2"]
}
```

This is just a small part of this file. I'll have to loop through the file to reach this information. Is there any other way , I can perform custom validations and return proper error messages to the user.

**EDIT 1:**

I have created the following RequestObj class:

public class RequestObj {

```
@Valid
@NotBlank
@NotNull
private String key1;

@Valid
@NotBlank
private String key2;

@Valid
@NotBlank
private String key3;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "RequestObj [key1=" + key1 + ", key2=" + key2 + ", key3=" + key3 + "]";
}
```

[image]

It is not validating key1 as not null.

postman request :

POST /validate HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8081
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "key2" :"gg",
    "key3" : "hh"
}

**EDIT 2:**
[image]

when I implement the validator interface. I dont get access to the mule Event. How will I access the json that I need to validate in this case ?

Comment: Can you provide more of the file you want to "look through"?  Moreover, I see a couple of problems been mentioned in your post, be explicit if you need help in both

Comment: you need to go for a custom json payload verified. you can use jackson json libraries to write your java code and refer the same in the mule flow.

Comment: @satishchennupati Can I validate the complete payload using the customValidator ?I tried implementing the Validator interface , But I didn't find the mule Event.Can you share any doc or code for reference ?

Comment: @satishchennupati  I have created the Request Object Class. Can you help me proceed further ?

Comment: @HeenaMittal  sure let me know If i can pass you on any links or some samples.

Comment: @satishchennupati Can you share a sample working code. Also I am unable to use payload annotation in my code. which maven dependeny should I add for that ? The other annotations that I have added for validation doesn't seem to work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you send me your complete xml at satishchennupati at the rate gmail.com

Comment: @satishchennupati https://github.com/Heena110297/validation-poc-3 Thanks for the help

Comment: @satishchennupati I have implemented custom error handling. How can I give business error codes to every custom validation ?

Comment: @HeenaMittal you can put your error codes in property files and assign them appropriately based on the scenario. Other way is you can implement custom logging.

Comment: Should I access the error codes in property file by creating a bean of message source ?

Comment: @satishchennupati  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59821078/how-to-access-property-from-property-file-in-java-code-mule-esb need your advice on this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

This is how my result looks after performing custom validations on the json input.
I used JSR-303 annotations for validating the data.

```
class Example{ 
   @NotBlank
        @Size(min = 3, max = 5)
        private String key1;

        @Pattern(regexp=".+@.+\\.[a-z]+") // email
        private String key2;

        private String key3;
}
```

then I wrote a custom validator and I invoked the static function validate by passing all the values:

```
public class ValidationServiceImpl {

    public static HashMap<String,String> validate(String key1 , String key2 , String key3)  {
        HashMap<String,String> result = new HashMap();
        Example req = new Example(key1 , key2, key3);
    Validator validator;
    ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Example>> violations = validator.validate(req);
    if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(violations)) {
        for (ConstraintViolation<Example> violation : violations) 
        {
            String propertyPath = violation.getPropertyPath().toString();
            String message = violation.getMessage();
            result.put(propertyPath, message);
        }
    }
    return result;
    }

}
```

The result is the hashmap which returns all the violations.Logging it will give you the result.

POM dependencies required are:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator-annotation-processor -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.el/javax.el-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.el -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the built-in JSON validator doesn't provide the validation or error reporting that you need, then you have to implement your own custom validator in Java. See the docs on how to implement a [custom validator](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/building-a-custom-validator#implement-the-validator-interface) by extending the Validator interface and in your implementation class you can use any Java library to validate JSON, like for example [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson). Then you can customize [the error handling](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/building-a-custom-validator#customizing-exception-class-and-message).

Comment: @Override
 public ValidationResult validate() {
  return null;
 }

Comment: When I implement the Validator , This is the default implementation , How will I access the mule Event in this case ?

Comment: The MuleEvent is the parameter of the validate() method:     ValidationResult validate(MuleEvent event);

Comment: import org.mule.extension.validation.api.Validator , is this the correct validator ?

Comment: why are the annotation not working. I have added @NotBlank . But it doesn't work

Comment: Hi , can you please check the EDIT 2 in my question above ? I have tried the approach you suggested. Need some help

Comment: I see now that you are using Mule 4. My answer is for Mule 3 and it is not valid for Mule 4. Please see the comment by @afelisatti in your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59529130/how-to-access-the-payload-when-implementing-the-validator-interface. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Also , I am unable to use @Payload annotation in mule 4 . How do I pass the whole payload to java function ? Thanks for the help

Comment: That's a different question. Please post as a new question.