# How to access the payload when implementing the validator interface?

Tags: validation, anypoint-studio, dataweave, mule-esb, mulesoft

[image]

I have to validate the incoming json payload and throw custom errors if the json is not valid. I tried implementing the validator interface as shown in the above image. But how should I access the payload now?In earlier versions the method accepted a mule event through which we could easily get the payload:

```
public interface Validator
{

    /**
     * Performs the validation and generates a
     * {@link ValidationResult} back.
     *
     * @param event the current {@link MuleEvent}
     * @return a {@link ValidationResult}
     */
    ValidationResult validate(MuleEvent event);
}
```

Comment: I do not believe that interface is meant to be implemented by users. You should just create your own custom SDK module https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/getting-started

Comment: @afelisatti But I need custom validations with custom error messages.

Comment: A validator is just an operation that fails if it does not like the input and does nothing if it does. There's no actual need to use that interface.