# How to access property from property file in java code( Mule ESB)

Tags: mule, esb

I am trying to fetch a property from the properties file in java code written in mule.

```
Class Example {
@NotBlank("message" = "${prop1}")
String key1;
String key2;
}
```

`prop1` is a property stored in properties file

```
prop1 = " 001 | key1 cannot be blank"
```

I want `prop1` to be resolved as `001 | key1 cannot be blank`. `${propname}` doesn't work. I can't use the value annotation as I want to save the value of the property in the message.

Comment: Is the question for Mule 3 or Mule 4?

Comment: @aled it is for Mule 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach for this is to not depend on any Mule specific code and deal with the property as you would any other argument, just passing it as a parameter. So when instantiating or calling a certain method, you'd just pass in the property at the Mule side:

```
<java:new class="com.me.Person" constructor="Person(String, Integer)">
    <java:args>#[{
      name: Mule::p('prop1'),
      age: 30
    }]</java:args>
</java:new>
```

Otherwise you'll depend on how that Java code is loaded since you'll need to inject a [ConfigurationProperties](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-api/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mule/runtime/api/component/ConfigurationProperties.java) instance and use it to resolve your property:

```
  @Inject
  private ConfigurationProperties configurationProperties;

  String getProperty(String name) {
     return configurationProperties.resolveStringProperty(name).orElse(null);
  }
```

This means your Java code has to be part of an SDK module so the injection takes place.